Laravel 11 AJAX request just showing the response data, not executing the success function
Laravel 11 AJAX request only showing the response data instead of executing the success function in AJAX. I have added all the code below.
Index.blade.php:
<table id="employeesTable" class="table table-hover datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>


Script:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        fetchEmployees();

        function fetchEmployees() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/system/employee',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res.employees);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

In Controller:
public function index()
{
    $query = Employee::query();
    $employees = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

    return response()->json(["employees" => $employees]);
}

Response showing this -->
Response SS
I haven't found any solution yet!

You're going to the /system/employee endpoint, you're not going to the page that has the javascript on it/the index blade

No, I think the url is correct, because it's going to the controller and responding with data in json format. But the success function is not working (as shown in the code and image I provided, console.log() is not working)

Right, because if you look at the browser, you are going to /system/employee in your browser, so you are getting the json response. From the screenshot, you're not going to the URL that has the index.blade.php and javascript. There's no javascript to execute.

Hope you are right. How do I solve this problem?

You need two routes: One for the ajax, and one for the view. Create a route/controller to bring up the view, go to that in the browser, and hopefully the rest should work.

I created two routes and it successfully console.log() data. But whenever I create new data/user in another browser, main view browser tab, it doesn't update automatically with AJAX call.

Update: It worked, I used the setinterval method. Thanks!

Use the jquery .fail() function to read the error, but from what I see you need to add the url of your application either for the local environment or in production
url: BASE_URL + '/system/employee',


The solution is, basically we need two routes, one for the page view, another for the AJAX call.
